# ¿Fallo al ejecutar una query masiva PDO PHP Mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

No entiendo la razón por la cuál este código no funciona si lo ejecuto desde PHP pero si hago un `print_r()`, copio el código impreso, lo pego en phpmyadmin y lo ejecuto directamente en MySQL funciona correctamente.

El problema empieza a ocurrir cuando concateno la segunda query, es decir, cuando hago `$query .= segundo sql`, ya que, si ejecuto únicamente uno funciona correctamente.

```
$query = "LOAD DATA INFILE '".addslashes($file1)."'
    INTO TABLE t1
    (@row)
       SET CAMPO1 = TRIM(SUBSTR(@row,1,4)),
           CAMPO2 = TRIM(SUBSTR(@row,5,3)),
           CAMPO3 = TRIM(SUBSTR(@row,8,4)),
       ;";
    $query .= " LOAD DATA INFILE '".addslashes($file2)."'
    INTO TABLE t2
    (@row)
        SET CAMPO1 = TRIM(SUBSTR(@row,1,22)),
            CAMPO2 = TRIM(SUBSTR(@row,23,4)),
        ;";
$pdo->query($query);
```

He probado agregando un espacio antes de "LOAD" como pueden observar en la segunda query. También he probado un sinfín de combinaciones con las comillas y nada me funciona.

Error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:\\proyectos\\2.dat'
    INTO TAB...' at line 11 in C:\proyectos\myproject\main.php:176
Stack trace:
#0 C:\proyectos\myproject\main.php(176): PDO->query('LOAD DATA INFIL...')
```

Comment: Tiendo a pensar que es más óptimo ejecutar todo en una consulta que hacer N

Comment: He modificado la pregunta, añadiendo más información

Comment: Son alrededor de 20-40

Comment: he probado quitar la coma! no funciona!

Comment: Me parece que tu problema se debe a esto. Al utilizar [`$pdo->query`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php) por defecto toma las consulta y realizar una sentencia preparada, esto provoca que no puedas ejecutar múltiples consultas al mismo tiempo. Intentá descativarlo primero así `$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, 0);` y después ejecuta tu consulta. Otra opción es que uses [`$pdo->exec`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.exec.php)

Comment: Sí, estoy usando ->prepare() por cada sentencia y luego un $query->execute(); y funciona correctamente. ¿Crees que si pongo todas esas sentencias en un .sql y hago una sóla línea que llame a ese SQL que a su vez contenga todos los LOAD FILE (una marca masiva de una carga masiva) funcione correctamente?

Comment: Carlos, te soy sincero no me convence la idea de hacer todo en una sola consulta. Hacerlo 1 a 1 tal vez no sea más rápido pero si te otorga mayor flexibilidad, por ejemplo, si ocurre un error, saber cuál falla y logearlo, si se captura el error, se puede continuar con la siguiente, etc. ¿Probaste hacer lo que te comente antes?

Answer (score 0):

Lo que estas haciendo es ejecutar en pdo multiples consultas en un solo llamado (hilo) primero debes verificar que tu base de datos este configurado para ello debes Abrir el archivo de configuración de MySQL (my.cnf o my.ini) y agrega o modifica (buscala) la siguiente línea:

```ini
multi_statements = On
```

Si esto ya estaba configurado o ya lo configuraste nos vamos al paso dos, que es dentro de tu PDO colocar en tus opciones de conexion lo siguiente: "MYSQL_ATTR_MULTI_STATEMENTS".

Aqui te doy un ejemplo del codigo ya que no proporcionas el mismo:

```ini
$dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=tu_base_de_datos';
$username = 'tu_usuario';
$password = 'tu_contraseña';

$options = [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_MULTI_STATEMENTS => true,
];

try {
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);

    

} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Error de conexión: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Alberto, no encontré "multi_statements" en el fichero de configuración de MySQL, no obstante, añadí la línea "multi_statements = On" y al apagar/enceder el servidor de MySQL ya no me dejaba encenderlo, tuve que quitar dicha línea.